# How to get the first class from two same classes with cheerio

Tags: javascript, node.js, cheerio

currently i'm making a web scraper with node.Js using cheerio. i want to get the data inside the first of `class="panel-items-list`.

the html look like this

```
<div class="margin-bottom-=30">
  <div class="side-list-panel">
    <ul class="panel-item-list">...</ul>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="margin-bottom-=30">
  <div class="side-list-panel">
    <ul class="panel-item-list">...</ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

i already did like this

```
const relateArticle = $('.panel-items-list').map((i, section)=>{
                    let articles = $(section).find('h5');
                    return articles.text();

                }).get();
```

but it return the data from both `class="panel-items-list"`. how do i get data just from one class ? sorry my english is bad. thanks in advance !

Comment: try adding the index of the element you want .get(0)

Comment: the class you are selecting is `panel-items-list` but its actually `panel-item-list` in your HTML....

Comment: Your '.panel-items-list' selector doesn't meet any of the elements you present in the markup, could you had more context to the example?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To get the first class only from the `.panel-item-list` use `.get(0)` that means you are only selecting the first index found using `.map`

Also, in your current `code` `jQuery` your are not selecting the right `class` selector.

In addition use [.trim()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/trim) method when getting the text to clean up any **unseen spaces** within the text.

**Live Working Demo:**

```js
const relateArticle = $('.panel-item-list').map((i, section) => {
  let articles = $(section).find('h5');
  return articles.text().trim();
}).get(0)

console.log(relateArticle) //Foo
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="margin-bottom-=30">
  <div class="side-list-panel">
    <ul class="panel-item-list">
      <h5>
        Foo
      </h5>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="margin-bottom-=30">
  <div class="side-list-panel">
    <ul class="panel-item-list">
      <h5>
        Bar
      </h5>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use first():

```
$('.panel-items-list').first().find('h5').text()
```